# How to create directory in nougat 7.0 .. All devices work fine below nougat 7.0 but in nexus 5x not creating directory

Tags: android-studio

I put this in manifest

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="true"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Creating Path Xml in Res

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Java code follows:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sheep Drench Calculations " );
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Please find attached the report generated from the Sheep Drench App");
                Uri pdfURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(EmailSend.this,
                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                        (new File(pdfDir ,"ResultPDF.pdf")));
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (pdfURI));
                startActivity(shareIntent);
```

More java code:

```
File pdfDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Dir");
                    if (!pdfDir.exists()) {
                        pdfDir.mkdir();
                    }
```

it creates directory but when it go to inside the directory it through exception no such directory or file .
            I tried this one to send email from file but problem is still there ..and director is not created ...

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing .mkdir() to .mkdirs () and make sure you've  Write External Storage permission in manifest

Comment: I think in Nougat 7.0 the file system behavior is totally changed that is why this problem is occur ... what is the solution . if any one know please let me know ... Thanks

Comment: Have worked in my place. Thanks @Abhinandan Chakraborty

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks a lot! It seems .mkdir() doesn't work in API < 29, but changing it to .mkdirs() solved the problem.